# How to combine a standalone application with an Android application?

Tags: java, android, gradle

How do I combine a standalone Java application with an Android application?

I have a piece of code taken from the Google quick start examples that perform a task that I can't seem to be able to combine with my activity source code.

I'm of course talking about the following Google example: [Sheet API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java), if I just add it as a standalone class and tell Android Studio to run this application, before my Android application, then it will produce what the code is suppose to do.

If I try to copy and paste the exact code into one of my activities it will give a couple of problems. One is that it can not find my keystore, another is a threading issue which I understand, another being that it can not find the credentials (even if the file is present), the newTrustedTransport-method call will be an issue, the setDataStoreFactory-method call will be an issue, file creation even with the correct uses-permissions and so on.

What is going on in the background that would make exactly the same source code work in one instance and not the other? What do I not know about Android Studio, and how an Android project works in the background for me having these issues?

I had an idea that I could just keep this standalone application as it is and store a file with the result that this Sheet example would provide me. But, since I do not have enough experience with Android Studio I have no idea if the result will be available for the actual Android application once it was made into a release. Will it? I can't save the output file generated by the Sheet example, under the res-folder, under the app module for some reason (scope?).

With other words... Can I have a standalone application, that is tasked to run before the Android application, to gather data and it will be doing this EACH time the Android application is run on a client? I feel like it would be stupid if the IDE would present this like this would actually work but then when the application is made into a release then the standalone application will not "follow" and be part of the release...

If I could just combine the source codes, I will not be having this issue at all. No examples online, neither Github or Youtube can provide me with answers on how to do this. Many examples online provide me with source code that is either out of date or just not what I'm looking for, and I really hate Google's way of explaining things. Just look at how they give code examples under this page: [Google API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/), and not give a full example where they would fit into the a project. Maybe all I need to make everything work is to use the code under "The library runs on Android 4.0 or higher (@Beta)."

Comment: try to add that project as "New module" i android project

Comment: @TejpalBh : Really? I can add a custom module? I believed they had to be of a specific type...